# Automated image update with page statistics

Tags: php, image, statistics, review

Frankly I am not sure where this would go but I assume the way to create what I'm about to describe is PHP... so I'm sorry if it's in the wrong section.

Basically I have a website, using Wordpress, where users can review websites and post a 5 star rating of the site. Each reviewed website has it's own dedicated page.
So what I want to do is create an image from the statistics of the ratings to allow the website owners to place it on their page. The image will need to, when clicked, go to that it's review page.

So the image would be about 150x150. Have the overall 5 Star Rating, the Name of the Reviewed site and the name of my website. It would also be cool if there was some automatically generated HTML embedding code so the site owners can simply copy and paste it.

I hope I explained myself ok. I've tried searching google but I'm not entirely sure what to search for and therefore have found nothing useful.

Thanks.

*EDIT*
I can create the embed code manually. I just need to really know about how to make the picture update automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey what you are asking for is quite complex and it would be to easy to just give you code. So here is some reading for you. Your problem is quite meaty and no doubt you'll learn loads sorting it out....

http://www.phptutorial.info/learn/create_images/

http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=20&title=How-to-create-bar-graph-in-PHP-with-dynamic-scaling

Comment: I didn't expect people to just give me the code :) I'd rather learn what I'm doing instead of just copy and pasting. Thanks for the links :)

Comment: @Novis no worries dude. You'd be surprised at how many people do just expect you to give them "teh codez" :P

Answer (score 1):

> I just need to really know about how
> to make the picture update
> automatically.

Just put URL to your php-script, which will generate image.
You will need function [imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) to write text over the image, [imagecopy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) to draw the stars (of votes).
Also, you will need image of a star and background.

So, approx. algorithm will be:

1. Open the background image by [imagecreatefrompng](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) - it will be our generated image
2. Open the Star image
3. Write title of the reviewed site by imagetttftext
4. Draw stars by copying existing Star image to our background image (by imagecopy)
5. Print generated image by [imagepng](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)

Comment: Thanks, I don't even know how to generate images with PHP though :P But will research that now